# Multiprocessing in Python crashes when code reaches start()

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am new in Python. I tried to use some multiprocessing to make my work faster. First I tried an example and everything worked fine. Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def f(name, n, m):
    if name == 'bob':
        time.sleep(2)
    print 'hello', name, ' ', n, m

def h():
    g(1, 2, 3)

def g(a, s, d):
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob', a, s,))
    t = Process(target=f, args=('helen', s, d,))
    p.start()
    t.start()
    t.join()
    p.join()
    print("END")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Start")
    h()
```

After that I used the same technique to my code and errors appeared. This is a part of the problematic code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    night_crawler_steam()

def night_crawler_steam():
    .
    .
    .
    multi_processing(max_pages, url, dirname)
    .
    .
    .

def multi_processing(max_pages, url, dirname):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        my_url = str(url) + str(page)
        soup = my_soup(my_url)
        fgt = Process(target=find_game_titles, args=(soup, page, dirname,))
        fl = Process(target=find_links, args=(soup, page, dirname,))
        fgt.start() #<-----------Here is the problem
        fl.start()
        fgt.join()
        fl.join()
        page += 1

def find_links(soup, page, dirname):
.
.
.

def find_game_titles(soup, page, dirname):
.
.
.
```

When the interpreter reaches fgt.start() some errors appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/��������/Desktop/MY PyWORK/NightCrawler/NightCrawler.py", line 120, in <module>
    night_crawler_steam()
  File "C:/Users/��������/Desktop/MY PyWORK/NightCrawler/NightCrawler.py", line 23, in night_crawler_steam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    multi_processing(max_pages, url, dirname)
  File "C:/Users/��������/Desktop/MY PyWORK/NightCrawler/NightCrawler.py", line 47, in multi_processing
    fgt.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    save(state)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 886, in load_eof
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
    raise EOFError
    save(v)
EOFError
```

This goes on and on till `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Any idea would be helpful!

Comment: Is the error still the same if you pass `None` instead of `soup`? It looks like it could be a problem with pickling.

Comment: It's not the same Error. After using None I just have problem with the functions that use soup. I see that the multiprocessing was done right. Any idea how to this pickling problem?

Comment: could you paste your methods body which you use in process instance? find_links etc. I think there is a problem

Comment: I found the problem. Multiprocessing doesn't accept soup as arg of the function that contains. So I use a function soup_to_string to pass it as an arg and after passing I use string_to_soup. Thanks for the help @janbrohl you opened my eyes!

Comment: In most cases using [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) is both simpler and faster than working with Processes directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with [pickling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) `soup` (see [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines)) so a simple solution would be to move the call `my_soup(my_url)` into the target functions like so:

```
def multi_processing(max_pages, url, dirname):        
    p=Pool() # using a pool is not necessary to fix your problem
     for page in xrange(1,max_pages+1):
        my_url = str(url) + str(page)
        p.apply_async(find_game_titles, (my_url, page, dirname))
        p.apply_async(find_links, (my_url, page, dirname))
    p.close()
    p.join()

def find_links(url,page, dirname):
    soup=my_soup(url)
    #function body from before


def find_game_titles(url, page, dirname):
    soup=my_soup(url)
    #function body from before
```

(Of course you can also pass soup in a pickle-able format but depending on what `my_soup` does exactly it might or might not be worth it.)

While not totally necessary it is normal to put the `if __name__=="__main__":` part in the end of the file.

Also you migth want to have a look at [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)'s other methods as they may fit better, depending on what your functions do.